# Restore a .bak file to a newer SQL server version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I'm facing a huge problem. I'm trying to restore a database to a newer version of SQL server.
I have been told that it is possible to go upwards - to newer versions - but never backwards.

The .bak file was saved with SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600) and i'm currently working with SQL server version 2012

Unfortunately i read the following error:

> The media family on device 'c:******' is incorrectly formed. SQL
>   Server cannot process this media family.

Can anyone help me to restore this database?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try restoring the .bak on R2, if that works it isn't corrupted. and with your 2012, maybe its an express instance and the backup is too large?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/media-family-on-device-is-incorrectly-formed-sql-server-cannot-process-this-med Duplicate?

Comment: Look with a hey editor at the start of the file. What does it look like? Egregious errors are usually visible (like all-zeros or missing file signature). In such a case the transfer was somehow broken. Post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try generating script with 'Schema and data' option.

Answer (score 0):

The backup file can be corrupted, or it can be from newer version of SQL Server. Try getting fresh backup and restoring it. Restoring SQL Server 2008 R2 backups on SQL Server 2012 is fully supported. And double check the target instance name. Maybe by accident you're trying to restore not in intended instance. It happens :-)